# Bitwise operation between scalar and vector

Tags: system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I am struggling to find a way to apply the bitwise operator between scalar and vector e.g:

```
logic [7:0] vec ;
logic scal;
logic [7:0] ans;
assign ans= vec | scal; // scal extend by appending zeros.
```

here only ans[0] is modified and rest a[7:1] have zeros. I need to apply the bitwise operator on the whole `vec`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a rabbit. I'll open with the *replication operator*:

```
{  <N>  { <some value> } }
```

which replicates `<some value>` `N` times. So you'll need:

```
assign ans= vec | {8{scal}};
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be much clearer to show the intent of the functionality rather than trying to write in terms of boolean expressions. Use the conditional operator which reads like if/else.

```
assign ans = scal ? '1 : ver;
```